# Comparar valor de Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

É possível varrer uma div e retornar o valor dela. Por exemplo:

```
<div class='result' id='add9' align='middle'> 1</div>
<div class='result' id='add9' align='middle'> 2</div>
<div class='result' id='add9' align='middle'> 3</div>
```

Temos uma div com valor 1, valor2 e valor 3. Abaixo, tem esta sintaxe via jquery:

```
$( "td" ).find( "div" );
```

Esta sintaxe varre a DIV e faz algo, com ela. Consigo após "varrer" a div, fazer uma comparação dos valores retornados? Usando como exemplo os valores acima: 1, 2, e 3?

Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim podes. Com `$('td').find('div');` tens uma coleção com os elementos, e para ter uma array/coleção com os seus valores podes fazer assim:

```
var valores = els.get().map(function(el) {
  return Number(el.innerHTML.trim());
});
```

### Exemplos:

#### Usar os numeros para os comparar:

```js
var els = $("td").find("div");
var valores = els.get().map(function(el) {
  return Number(el.innerHTML.trim());
});

console.log(valores);
console.log('o primeiro valor é', valores[0] > valores[1] ? 'maior' : 'menor');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='result' id='add9' align='middle'> 1</div>
      <div class='result' id='add9' align='middle'> 2</div>
      <div class='result' id='add9' align='middle'> 3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Usar os numeros para mudar atributos/características no DOM

```js
var els = $("td").find("div");
var valores = els.get().forEach(function(el) {
var nr = el.innerHTML.trim()
  if (nr == '1') el.style.color = 'purple';
  if (nr == '2') el.style.color = 'red';
  if (nr == '3') el.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='result' id='add9' align='middle'> 1</div>
      <div class='result' id='add9' align='middle'> 2</div>
      <div class='result' id='add9' align='middle'> 3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Consigo por exemplo, setar um color="red" se o valor for igual a 2 por exemplo? Como poderia fazer? Grato.

Comment: @user54154 sim, juntei mais um exemplo.

Comment: Deu certo. Muito obrigado mesmo.